# How to Lower Minimum CPU Clock Frequency

Tags: 20.04, power-management, cpu, amd-processor, overclocking

Recently I've been trying to reduce the cooling requirements of my desktop computer (since it gets exceedingly hot in summer), and have started looking into underclocking my CPU.
Currently it idles at around 2.2 GHz, which is far higher then what I need it for on a daily basis. The trouble seems to be, according to `cpufreq-info`, that the 'hardware limit' of my CPU is fixed at 2.20 GHz to 4.85 GHz, and therefore none of the governors can go lower then 2.2 GHz.

**I would like to reduce this 'hardware limit' down to 1 GHz**, but can't find any way to do it, neither in the BIOS nor with any command line or GUI tools. How can I achieve that (ideally in such a way that I can still use the usual CPU governors should I need higher performance)?

I'm using the following:

- Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
- [AMD Ryzen™ 7 5800X](https://www.amd.com/en/product/10466)
- [ROG Strix X570-E Gaming](https://rog.asus.com/us/motherboards/rog-strix/rog-strix-x570-e-gaming-model/spec)

Any advice or ideas would be greatly appreciated

A sample of `cpufreq-info`:

```
  driver: acpi-cpufreq
  CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: 15
  CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: 15
  maximum transition latency: 4294.55 ms.
  hardware limits: 2.20 GHz - 4.85 GHz
  available frequency steps: 3.80 GHz, 2.80 GHz, 2.20 GHz
  available cpufreq governors: conservative, ondemand, userspace, powersave, performance, schedutil
  current policy: frequency should be within 2.20 GHz and 3.80 GHz.
                  The governor "powersave" may decide which speed to use
                  within this range.
  current CPU frequency is 2.79 GHz.
  cpufreq stats: 3.80 GHz:8.11%, 2.80 GHz:50.42%, 2.20 GHz:41.46%  (2365)
```

**EDIT:** I'll also take an explanation for why this isn't possible and what my alternatives, if any, are as an answer.

Comment: have you tried cpupower-gui.

Comment: @trondhansen Yes, it's also limited at 2200 MHz.

Comment: It is not related to Ubuntu. You can reduce timing in BIOS as you like. But this will reduce max freq too.

Comment: Something like [CPU Power Manager for Gnome Shell](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/945/cpu-power-manager/)?

Comment: @PabloBianchi I'm afraid I've already tried that too, minimum frequency won't go below 58%

Comment: Please read this: https://lenovopress.lenovo.com/lp0826.pdf for all the commands and limitations. If the scaling_available_frequencies does not show a value below 2.2 this is impossible to change from within the OS. It would require a BIOS upgrade from the manufacturer. That document is related to thinkpads but works as a general guideline for all.

Comment: It might also be a good idea to install 22.04. Newer kernels tend to need less power.

Comment: @Rinzwind Am I right in saying that, if the manufacturer's BIOS doesn't allow changing the frequencies, I'd have to flash a custom BIOS to get it working? Does such a thing even exist?

Comment: Yes and yes. -And- the core needs to be physically able to go lower.

Comment: @Rinzwind Why would the CPU not be able to be underclocked? I can't think of a situation where running at a lower frequency would be damaging.

Comment: @ALambentEye because it would stop working as it does not receive enough power.

Answer (score 0):

Reasons (not an extensive list) why CPUs have minimum "safe" frequencies:

1. **PLLs:** Clock frequencies (cycling frequencies) are generated by PLLs, or
   phase locked loops, which take a reference clock, and perform
   modifications on the signal (in simple terms, multiplication or
   division) to reach the preferred frequency. This will limit the
   range of the clock, meaning that there will be a certain minimum
   frequency.
2. **Other Components:** The CPU is the main communication point between other machine components, more prevalent here being DRAM (dynamic random-access memory). DRAM needs to be constantly provided a clock, or there may be memory "lost" in missing clock cycles. Depending on the motherboard, CPU, DRAM, or other clocked components, this clock may or may not be provided by the CPU. If there are connected circuits making use of synchronous logic components (components that require a shared, constant clock cycle to run), that are receiving their clocks from the CPU, the CPU would need to provide at least that frequency.

Comment: Technically correct but not an answer to the question ;) It would be better to include for an AMD Ryzen™ 7 5800X so it explains why this is not possible (I know older cores had a min. of 800Hz with 800Hz increments; this Ryzen probably has 2200 as the min. with 100, 400 or 800 increments). But ... I could not find a source myself :D

Comment: Good call, @Rinzwind - I did some digging as well and was also unable to find Ryzen specific documentation. I did find some other miscellaneous posts referencing minimum clock speeds; [1 - Ryzen minimum discussion, Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/AMDLaptops/comments/ojifwm/is_138ghz_the_minimum_frequency_of_the_ryzen_7/), [2 - CPU Scaling docs, ArchLinux](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/CPU_frequency_scaling), [3 - More Ryzen minimum discussion, TechPowerUp](https://www.techpowerup.com/forums/threads/ryzen-3200u-and-idle-clocks-how-to-get-the-lowest-clock-400mhz-i-think.260529/).